# Library to cluster circular data

Tags: data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means, gaussian, circular-dependency

I have an array of data that describes the number of people at a restaurant which is also a nightclub. The data distribution is as follows:

[image: customers at club]

I assume customer distributions to be approximately gaussian, so if it were weighted 1D data that wasn't directional I would be able to find clusters relatively easily using Gaussian Mixture Models. However, in this case, since data that ends at hour 23 continues at 0 (i.e., is directional), it is less trivial. How could I cluster this data using python (either with or without specifying the number of clusters). I have looked into sklearn, and some other libraries, but haven't been able to find anything, though. Looking at the data, we can immediately identify clusters at around 0 and 12.5, so I am thinking that this could be done in quite an efficient manner. I have found [spherecluster](https://pypi.org/project/spherecluster/) which seems to be able to do this on the unit hypersphere, however, I am looking at a solution that works on a simple 2D circle. Does anybody have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an algorithm myself, maybe useful for people encountering a similar problem in the future. It is a weighted 1D clustering for circular data. Testing it on data, I have seen it to often get stuck in local minima, so maybe so more refining is necessary to achieve desirable performance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def circ_dist(point, data_pts, r):
        min_dists = []
        for data in data_pts:
            min_dist = np.min([np.abs(point - data), r - np.abs(point - data)])
            min_dists.append(min_dist)
        return min_dists

def get_circstats(data, weights, high):
    """
    Calculate the weighted circular mean and circular standard deviation.
    """
    # Convert data to radians
    data = data * 2 * np.pi / high
    # normalise weights
    weights = weights / np.sum(weights)
    # Calculate the numerator and denominator of the circular mean
    numerator = np.sum(weights * np.sin(data))
    denominator = np.sum(weights * np.cos(data))
    # Calculate the circular mean and convert back to original scale
    circular_mean = np.arctan2(numerator, denominator) * high / (2 * np.pi)
    circular_mean = circular_mean % high
    # Calculate the circular std and convert back to original scale
    circular_std = np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(np.sqrt(numerator**2 + denominator**2) / np.sum(weights)))
    circular_std = circular_std * high / (2 * np.pi)
    return (circular_mean, circular_std)


class CircularWeightedKMeans:
    def __init__(self, n_clusters, max_iter=300):
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.iteration = 0
        self.centroids = None
        self.prev_centroids = None
        self.std = None
        self.r = None
        self.fac = None
        self.clust_weights = None
    def fit(self, X_train, weights, r):
        self.r = r
        self.fac = 2*np.pi/self.r
        self.centroids = [random.choice(X_train)]
        for _ in range(self.n_clusters-1):
            dists = circ_dist(self.centroids[-1], X_train, self.r)
            dists /= np.sum(dists)
            new_centroid_idx, = np.random.choice(range(len(X_train)), size=1, p=dists)
            self.centroids += [X_train[new_centroid_idx]]
        while np.not_equal(self.centroids, self.prev_centroids).any() and self.iteration < self.max_iter:
            self.prev_centroids = self.centroids
            self.clust_weights = [0]*self.n_clusters
            self.std = [0]*self.n_clusters
            sorted_pts = [[] for _ in range(self.n_clusters)]
            sorted_weights = [[] for _ in range(self.n_clusters)]
            for x, w in zip(X_train, weights):
                # assign each point to closest centroid
                dists = circ_dist(x, self.centroids, self.r)
                closest_centroid_idx = np.argmin(dists)
                self.clust_weights[closest_centroid_idx] += w
                sorted_pts[closest_centroid_idx].append(x)
                sorted_weights[closest_centroid_idx].append(w)
            for idx, _ in enumerate(self.centroids):
                # weighted mean of all points in cluster gives new centroid
                self.centroids[idx], self.std[idx] = get_circstats(np.array(sorted_pts[idx]), np.array(sorted_weights[idx]), self.r)
                self.clust_weights[idx] = np.sum(np.array(sorted_weights[idx]))
            self.clust_weights = [w/np.sum(self.clust_weights) for w in self.clust_weights]
            self.iteration += 1

    def plot(self, X_train, weights):
        # Histogram 
        plt.hist(X_train, bins=20, weights=weights)
        sizes = self.clust_weights/np.max(self.clust_weights)*200
        # draw std as lines 
        for i, centroid in enumerate(self.centroids):
            # random color
            color = np.random.rand(3,)
            plt.scatter(centroid, max(weights)/2*sizes[i]/max(sizes), s=sizes[i], zorder=2, color=color, label=f'Cluster {i}, x={int(centroid)}, weight {self.clust_weights[i]/np.sum(self.clust_weights):.2f}, std {self.std[i]:.2f}')
            y_range = 2*[max(weights)/2*sizes[i]/max(sizes)]
            plt.plot([centroid-self.std[i], centroid+self.std[i]], y_range, zorder=1, color=color)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```